# CSS overlay close button scrolls to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a pure CSS solution that on click of an anchor shows an overlay image on top of a div. It works fine except the close button scrolls to the top of the page when clicked, I would like it to close and then remain at the current location on the page. I tried adding a div ID to the href but then the overlay doesn't close, can this be done with only CSS? Any help appreciated, many thanks.

```css
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="./assets/map-overlay.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change your link href to #!

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've wanted to stop the clicking of a link from scrolling to the top of the page, for me I've used `href="#!"` and that has worked for preventing the scroll to top of page

Answer (score 0):

Change the `href="#"` by `href="#!"`

```css
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
  <!-- Change the href="#" by href="#!"-->
    <a class="close" href="#!">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="./assets/map-overlay.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works..except the page still jumps up a little when the image is closed?